# is the text describing Tennessee as a state with only small towns?

Tags: meaning-in-context, headlinese

the headline is:

"Incomes are low in small-town Tennessee, but so is the cost of living. That attraction could be a key to reviving many rural areas."

I can't figure out if the text is describing Tennessee as a state with only small towns

OR if the text is talking about one specific town that is small situated in Tennessee.

Which one is it?

Comment: It means neither. See answer.

Answer (score 2):

small-town Tennessee **means** those parts of Tennessee where there are small towns.
Not places like Nashville, Memphis or Knoxville which are major cities.

If you say: small towns in Tennessee, you are saying the same thing.

In AmE the term small-town is often used as an adjective.

She's a small-town girl. That means she is not from a city or large town.

Answer (score 1):

By 'in small-town *somewhere*' we mean 'in typical small towns in *somewhere*'.

> small-town
>
> adjective [ before noun ]
>
> used to refer to small social groups where ordinary people live:
>
> *The film explores the life of small-town America in the 1930s.*

[small-town (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/small-town)

Comment: so it is a standardized phrase right? It is very cofusing to standard a pgrase under that construction for someone learning English. Thank you!